# With jackson, how to serialize only some property of an ebean object when it is part of another object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, ebean

I have an API I can call to get some Json objects. Let's say I have two kind of objects : `A` and `B` .

an `A` objects have a `B` object amongst its instance variables. When I call my API to get `someB`, I want the following result :

```
{
  id: 234,
  name: theBName,
  colour: theBColour,
  size: 123
}
```

but when I call my API to get `someA`, I want the following result :

```
{
  id: 456,
  type: someAType,
  b: {
    id: 234,
    name: theBName
  }
}
```

As you can see, my `B` object only have parts of its properties in the second case.

I have found how to serialize some proporties and not others using `jsonViews` . I also know how to serialize an object as only its `id` when serialized as part of another object by adding :

```
 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
 @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
 public B someB;
```

to my `A` object.

But for the life of me, i can't figure out how to serialize this `B` object as its `id` *AND* other properties of my choice when, and only when, it is serialized as part of an `A` object.

I am looking for something like an annotation like this :

```
@serialiazeUsingOnlyProperties({"property1", "property2"})
public B someB;
```

to put in my A object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. The annotation is commonly used at the class level but it applies to fields as well. when applied to a field, it is used to ignore properties inside the annotated field:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"colour", "size"})
public B someB;
```

Comment: oooh, that's a pretty good answer. I will wait 15 minutes to validate as required by SO, but this do solve my problem ! Would be easier with a white list than with a black list (I need 2 properties amonst 10 or 12) but this will do the job ! Thank you very much.

Comment: For information purpose : it seems white-listing properties is not yet supported but will be in the future : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1296